# abstract and reuse parts of a map command in vimrc

Tags: vim

I wrote a map command in vim that verges on the line of being too complicated for my taste. I'd like to:

1. Abstract away parts, or at least spit them into multiple lines and    explain each.
2. Reuse most of it with only 2 things, changing only 2 things in it each time.

The command uses the vim-pandoc plugin to create an Html file out of the current pandoc file and copy it to clipboard.

```
nnoremap <leader><leader>11 :w<cr>:Pandoc html<cr>:sleep 100m<cr>:e <c-r>=expand('%:r')<cr>.html<cr>ggVG"+y:b#<cr>:bd #<cr>
```

My first attempt is thus:

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader><leader>22 MyFunc()

func! MyFunc()
  let save = ':w<cr>'
  let runPandoc = ':Pandoc html<cr>'
  let sleep = ':sleep 100m<cr>'
  let viewResult = ':e ' . expand('%:r') . '.html' . '<cr>'
  let copyAll = 'ggVG"+y'
  let backToPrevBuf = ':b#<cr>'

  return save . runPandoc . sleep . viewResult . copyAll . backToPrevBuf
endfunc
```

However, this does not work because it has `<cr>` in the returned value instead of actually executing enter.

Using this I can pass an arg to MyFunc that will change the `html` portions to other filetypes.

My two questions are:

1. Is there a better, more direct way of abstracting away portions of long maps?
2. How can I solve the issue with the `<cr>` appearing in the result instead of actually meaning "Press the enter button".

Thanks for the help!

EDIT:

After getting suggestions I now have the current version, it seems a bit verbose.
While I can wrap the feedkeys to be a shorter name with the 'n' parameter, is there anything else I can do?

```
func! MyFunc()
  call feedkeys(":w\<cr>",'n')
  call feedkeys(":Pandoc html\<cr>",'n')
  call feedkeys(":sleep 100m\<cr>",'n')
  call feedkeys(':e ' . expand('%:r') . '.html' . "\<cr>",'n')
  "TODO read about :%y+ understand why it copies the entire file
  call feedkeys('ggVG"+y','n')
  call feedkeys(":b#\<cr>",'n')
endfunc
```

EDIT:

Finally, I've understood what it means to get rid of the feedkeys, and now I reached the final destination:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader><leader>22 :call MyFunc()<cr><cr>

func! MyFunc()
  w
  Pandoc html
  sleep 100m
  execute 'e' (expand('%:r') . '.html')
  %y+
  b#
endfunc
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: :h feedkeys() could do the trick for you.

Comment: Last trick, IIRC `:e %:r.html`, or even `:e %<.html` should work as well.

Comment: You could also avoid opening and closing a buffer with something like: `let @+ = join(readfile(expand('%:r).'.html'), "\n")`. Sometimes this is interesting to avoid triggering autocommands as they may have side effects, slow down the execution, etc.

Comment: Thanks! the join readfile is a great idea! However when I paste, it puts everything on a single line... It sounds like it should work... I don't see a literal \n written everywhere. Weird. EDIT: found the problem, my bad! It works and it's a great idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better, more direct way of abstracting away portions of
>   long maps?

Since you have already called a function, and the function just concatenate the `rhs` mappings, why not just do the actual work in your function, and just map to execute the function like :`nnoremap whatever :call yourFunc()<cr>`

> How can I solve the issue with the `<cr>` appearing in the result
>   instead of actually meaning "Press the enter button".

Use `"\<cr>"`

Comment: +1. By using a `:map-<expr>`, you're obfuscating things. @Kent is right, keep your function simple and let it do the job.

Comment: BTW, `copyall` simply becomes: `:%y+`.

Comment: So I've tried rewriting it according to your suggestions as well as @OSwaldo's comment and edited the post according to what I got, was this what you meant? It seems a bit verbose.

Comment: @PsyFish, you don't need `feedkey()`. Get rid of it.

Comment: Instead of feedkeys() what should I use? How to get those strings supplied as input? Or should I use something else instead of those strings?

Comment: @LucHermitte
I tried using the normal command instead but I can't get it to do even simple things like replace the `call feedkeys(":w\<cr>",'n')` in order to save. There's also the execute which isn't any less verbose with :execute "normal :w\<cr>"

Comment: All commands can be used directly -> `:w`. If you need to inject a dynamic variable into them, then you'll need `:exe` and not `:normal` -> `:exe 'w '.newfilename`. `exe "normal ...` is used to trigger normal and insert mode actions. They are the way we have to go into these modes from the command mode. Using them to go from the command mode to the command mode is obfuscation.